# Why can I only select one alignment?

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced

When I was making a character I created a Paladin with the Cavalier Class Kit, but when I went to choose an alignment I could only choose Lawful Good and was unable to select or view any of the other alignments in the list.

So I am wondering, can some classes/kits restrict which alignments you can choose from? or was there another reason why I could only select 1 alignment for my Cavalier.

Comment: Paladin can only be Lawful Good. I'm on mobile so I can't cite sources, but it's how Paladin works in all DnD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, some classes are restricted and they are as follows:

Fighters:

- Berserker - Chaotic or Neutral

Rangers - Good

Paladins - Lawful Good

- Blackguard - Evil (fallen Paladin)

Clerics:

- Talos - Evil
- Helm - Neutral
- Lathander - Good

Druids - True Neutral

Thief - Not Lawful Good

- Shadowdance - Not Lawful

Bard - Neutral

Monk - Lawful

- Sun Soul - Lawful Good
- Dark Moon - Lawful Evil

Barbarian - Neutral

Taken from [Baldurs Gate Wikia](http://baldursgate.wikia.com/wiki/Classes) and [GameFAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/663933-baldurs-gate-enhanced-edition/faqs/66126)